# VsCode launch json configuration for specific node version and use yarn start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, nvm

Couldn't find a solution to run `yarn start` in vscode debugger mode using a specific node version. launch.json file is as follows

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via Yarn",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${env:HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/node",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeArgs": ["start:debug"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any additional config to do this?
I'm using nvm for development.

Answer (score 0):

NVM relies on environment variable set in the shell, so make sure the setting shell VS Code is correctly set for the one you use, eg `zsh`. For example `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"`, other resources also mentioned setting `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": []`.

To check nvm is working in VS Code, when you open the terminal in VS Code can you do `nvm --version`? If not, the terminal for VS Code is not correctly set.

Then you need to setup the `runtimeVersion` as described in

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_multi-version-support

And the `runtimeExecutable` to be `yarn`

Example launch.json

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch via Yarn",
            "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
            "runtimeVersion": "16.13.2",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/next",
            "runtimeArgs": ["start"],
        }
```